# Angular 2 unique id for every component instance of jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, uniqueidentifier, angular-components

I have Angular 2 component contain jquery component and i want to generate id for every instance of my Angular 2 component  **because i need different jquery selector for each component**

this is my component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'full-calendar',
  templateUrl: 'full-calendar.html'
})
export class FullCalendarComponent {

ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
 
    $('angular2-fullcalendar').fullCalendar('option',changes.options.currentValue)
 
    }
  
}
```

i want to use more than one with different selector each time

i found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5145#issuecomment-256354115) solution

```
export class GetId {
  protected getId(id: number|string = _.uniqueId()): string {
    return _.lowerFirst(this.constructor.name) + '_' + id;
  }
}

class MyComponent extends GetId {
  ...    
}
```

and id can be used like this

`<input [id]="getId('name')" type="text">`

but i am still searching for built-in solution .

Comment: i need different jquery selector for each component .

Comment: why not use a class, and why use jquery?

Comment: i am using jquery component in angular 2 application, so i am using jquery inside component

Comment: why not use a class?

Comment: can you explain with example please ? i didn't understand

Comment: you don't know what a class is? can you post the jquery code that uses these ids?

Comment: check question now

Comment: You want a random id? is that what you want?

Comment: yes i want best solution for this using angular2

Comment: You don't need to use unique ids for that. Adding such a complexity for a simple thing like that does not make sense.

Comment: @n00dl3 how jquery will intact with many components have same selector it will be a problem

Comment: You should not use jQuery to traverse the DOM, and apply some transformations, if you really need to use jQuery, use it in a directive that you will apply on element in your templates. You are not supposed to mess with the DOM directly in Angular.

Comment: yse i am using jQuery in directive, directives in angular2 called components

Comment: no, components are components, [directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) are directives. But traversing the DOM to apply some transformations is a bad idea. How to deal with conditional rendering of some elements ? Will you traverse the dom on every change detection ? How to be sure the plugin you have applied on an element is really destroyed when the Angular renderer removes the element ? If you want to do things cleanly, you need to apply it using the template, not traversing the dynamically created DOM.

Comment: @n00dl3 yes sure 
thank you for explain this . i was relay mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a checkbox,

```
<input class="styled-checkbox" id="{{checkboxId}}" type="checkbox">
<label for="{{checkboxId}}">{{checkboxLabel}}</label>

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'checkbox',
    templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html'
})

export class CheckboxComponent {
    @Input() checkboxId:string;
    @Input() checkboxLabel:string;
}
```

in parent -->

```
<checkbox [checkboxId]="Math.random().toString(36).substring(2)"></checkbox>
```

Comment: how can you guarantee that you will not get the same ID if this is a random id? Unless every time you generate a random id you check if this id already exist in the document. If yes, generate again... but dont think that this is the best practice.

Comment: I used a slightly modified version of this to generate a `checkboxId` value in the typescript file that is then referenced as the `id` for the checkbox and `for` in the label.

Answer (score 3):

### Traversing the DOM: bad idea

You should not use jQuery to traverse the DOM and apply some transformations to it, here is why:

Jquery is tightly coupled with the DOM while angular tends to abstract all these interactions: when you modify the DOM in angular, you are supposed to use the `Renderer` API that will apply transformations on the elements. This is what allows rendering on Workers, building nativescript applications, etc.

Some problem may occur if you want to traverse the DOM from a parent component to apply modifications :

- Some elements can be added to or removed from the DOM dynamically by the Angular renderer. How to deal with elements that are rendered conditionally ? traversing on every change detection is an anti-pattern.
- How to be sure the plugin you applied on an element has been properly destroyed when the element has been removed by the angular renderer ?

### Sometimes you do need jQuery

If you do need to use jQuery, for example to apply a jQuery plugin on an element, it is a better practice to write a directive or a component and apply the plugin by adding the directive or component inside your template than traversing the DOM from a component.

You can create a directive like this :

**NB:** I have no idea of the full calendar API, so it is full improvisation.

```
@Directive({ selector: '[fullCalendar]' })
export class HighlightDirective implements OnInit,OnDestroy,OnChanges {
    private jqElement:any;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
       el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
    @Input()
    options:any={};

    ngOnInit(){
      this.jqElement = $(this.el.nativeElement);
      this.jqElement.fullCalendar(this.options);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes:{[k:string]:SimpleChange}){
      if(changes['options']&&!changes['options'].firstChange) // do not apply options on first change (jquery plugin not applied)
        this.jqElement.fullCalendar("option",this.options);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
      this.jqElement.fullCalendar("destroy");
    }
}
```

and apply it this way:

```
<div fullCalendar [options]="someOptions"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, i already implemented it this way . but question is not about this .
question is about creating many component with different id.
check the correct answer above

Answer (score 2):

A simple and elegant solution (found it [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/commit/b06d56c0878410e2ce92d0562bf6eb14449bbf54))

```
let searchBoxId = 0;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auto-complete',
  templateUrl: './auto-complete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auto-complete.component.less']
})

export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() searchBoxId = `search-box-${searchBoxId++}`;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const searchBox = document.getElementById(`${this.searchBoxId}`);
    //   Get your input unique id
    console.log("searchBox: ")
  }
}
```

- Set a global variable
- Each time the component is being used (loaded) - we counter up the variable
- Make sure you get the unique id from the DOM, only after it has been loaded (**ngAfterViewInit**)